# Trouble with relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I try to understand relative imports, but one situation isn't clear for me:
I have dir structure like that:

```
tests/
    subdir1/
        run.py
    subdir2/
        start.py
```

run.py costist this:

```
print('in run')
```

start.py consists:

```
from ..subdir1 import run
print('succesed')
```

but when I start start.py (python3 ./subfold2/start.py ) 
I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./subfold2/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..subfold1 import run
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

python version is 3.7.3
I tried to add **init**, but I read, that python 3.3+ dont need it to understand, that folder is package.

Answer (score 1):

Have a file `test.py` under `test` directory as the runner. Run from there and everything will work.

There should be `__init__.py` under every folder.

OR

Run

```
python -m package.subpackage.subsubpackage.pyscript
```

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand, what means "test.py as the runer": it must to start run.py, or start.py?
Added __init__.py to folders, it doesn't work with same error (am I right understand, that __init__.py can be empty files?)